# How do I print the entire decimal output (not in scientific notation)?

Tags: python

I am dividing a 100 digit number with a 1-2 digit number. The result I end up with is:

```
4.483392416946529e+99
```

How do I print all 99 digits of this number?

Wrapping the division with float() doesn't work at all.

Here is the code I used

```
from random import *

a = ''
for n in range(101):
    x = randint(0,9)
    a = a + str(x)

a = int(a)
a/7
```

I expected a 99 digit number rounded to two decimal places.

Comment: With float division, you can't. Float arithmetic does not have enough precision.

Comment: Taking into account how floating point numbers are stored in a computer you should not expect the 99th digit to be accurate.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon That seems so strange. Do you know of any libraries that have enough precision?

Comment: @zerosofthezeta Yes, the [fraction module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) exists for that

Comment: Or the decimal module

Comment: In that case, since we are dividing integers, the fraction module really is more appropritate. Otherwise, the decimal would be more appropriate

Comment: @DillonDavis Thanks! Decimal(a)/Decimal(7) with precision 102 did the trick!